# How to avoid duplicate insertion of records using teradata sql driver in python?

Tags: python, sql, teradata

I have a table created in teradata into which I am loading multiple records from each file that gets loaded in a folder. Some files can have duplicate records. Is there a way i can check for duplicates records before inserting them into a table and retain only one unique record?

```
num_of_chunks = 1000  #breaking the data into chunks 

#Insert Query
insert_query= "INSERT INTO db.table VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)" 

#set host, user, password params
host,username,password = 'x','y', "z"

#connet to DB using UdaExec
udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="IMC", version="1.0", logConsole=False)
        with udaExec.connect(method="odbc",system=host, username = username,
                         password=password, driver="Teradata") as session:
            file_exist=session.execute(file=r"\\path to a fastload script to 
            create a table in a db in teradata" ,fileType="bteq",ignoreErrors= 
            [3803])
            df_chunks = np.array_split(df, num_of_chunks)

            for i,_ in enumerate(df_chunks):

               data = [tuple(x) for x indf_chunks[i].to_records(index=False)]

               rows= session.executemany(insert_query, data,batch=True)
```

Comment: I would actually suggest that you load the file -- in batch  -- if possible into a staging table.  Then remove the duplicates in the database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That would then require me to do the entire process using a fastload and bteq scripts. I was looking for an alternative using the teradata sql driver, If there exists a parameter to pass to replace duplicates?

Comment: If it's an option for you, create your target table as a `SET` table.  Then when you do an `INSERT / SELECT` duplicate rows will automatically be ignored.  If you are inserting lots of rows into a `SET` table, though, the insert speed will gradually slow down due to the duplicate row checks.

Comment: #1: You could switch to MERGE (using WHEN NOT MATCHED only) instead of INSERT. '2: Regarding batch inserts there's a feature named *statement independence* which catches errors without rollback, but I don't know if the Python driver supports it. #3: You can create an *ERROR TABLE* to catch Duplicate Rows (never tried it with batch Inserts only Insert/Select)

Comment: Regarding set tables - FastLoad and TPT will silently reject duplicate records. Straight inserts will fail with duplicate row error. I don't know how executemany fits into that.